# how to use React Redux to display data without mapping method

Tags: reactjs, redux

My database generates this json data

```
[{"id":"1","firstName":"jmarkatti"}]
```

This **react redux** code displays records using mapping method and it works fine.

Now I have a requirements to display the record without mapping method to this effect, within render function, I have tried

any of the following code below

```
 Name: {pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />
 Name: {pg1.items1[0].firstName} <br />
 Name: {this.props.pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />
```

**but it keeps dsiplaying error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Recording1.render**

In **Reactjs**, I can just  do something like

```
Name:  {this.state.rec[0].firstName} <br />
```

but in **react redux**, It shows error mentioned above

here is the main **React Redux** code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { uActions } from '../actions';

class Recording1 extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
this.state = {};

       }

    componentDidMount() {
this.props=this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll_Rec());
}

render() {
        const { pg1, pgs1 } = this.props;
        return (
           <div>      
              {pgs1.items1 &&
<ul>
// display record with mapping metthod
  {pgs1.items1.map((pg1, i) =>
<li key={pg1.id}>
 Name: {pg1.firstName} <br />
</li>
)}

</ul>
 }


           <div>

// display records without mapping method

 //Name: {pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />
 //Name: {pg1.items1.firstName} <br />
 //Name: {this.props.pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />

                   </div>

</div>

);
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { pgs1} = state;
    const { pg1 } = state;
    return {
        pg1,
        pgs1
    };
}


const connectedRecording1 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Recording1);
export { connectedRecording1 as Recording1 };
```

here is the **Redux Reducer**

```
export function pgs1(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {



case userConstants.GETALL_REQUEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true
  };
case userConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
  return {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
items1: action.pgs1
  };
```

**An update**

service API Call

```
function getAll_Rec(us) {

    const req = {
        method: 'POST',

       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({us})
    };
        return fetch(`record.php`, req).then(handleResponse)
     .then(pg1 => {

            if (pg1) {
               console.log(pg1);
            }

            return pg1;
        });
}
```

Comment: Does this.props.pg1 return your array containing the objects?

Comment: @JP4 {this.props.pg1} shows nothing

Comment: What do you get with this.props?

Comment: it throws error bundle.js:871 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {match, location, history, staticContext, pg1, pgs1, dispatch}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can you put it in a console.log to see what it gets? Don't render anything.

Comment: pgs1 should be the array of objects you are trying to render correct? pg1 is undefined because when you are mapping through you are renaming the individual objects in you array. If you want to access those objects without mapping, I think something like this.props.pgs1.items1[0].firstName should work. Or since you destructured it, pgs1.items1[0].firstName.

Comment: with console.log it shows [Object Object]

Comment: So now try console.log(this.props.pgs1, this.props.pg1) to see the what the structure of your objects are.

Comment: @SEANULUS  your solution shows error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Recording1.render (bundle.js:58855)

Comment: @JP4 console.log(this.props.pgs1) shows [Object Object]

Comment: We want to see whats in the props so console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.pgs1))

Comment: @JP4 console.log JSON.stringify() returns empty brackets {}. the record has already been json stringfy. I have updated my post 
to reflect the service api call showing  how record has been json stringfy. Please see updated part of the post between thanks so far

Comment: If we could see the structure of your state it would help a lot, since your mapping part of your state to the component props, it would be helpful to see the entire props for the component. You could console.log the props in your constructor and stringify it if needed. You can also use react dev tools and redux dev tool extensions to help see your state. I need to see more then [object object] from your props.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(state) in mapStateToProps before you destructure? Above const { pgs1 } = state

Comment: Also, what does the console.log in your API call return? Are you using async middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to to show the data like this.

```
 Name: {this.props.pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />
```

Try this one.

```
 Name: {this.props && this.props.pgs1 && this.props.pgs1.items1 && 
               this.props.pgs1.items1.firstName} <br />
```

Because most of the time when we render the data to the DOM props can be undefined. So avoid that issue check whether props have been received first using AND for every break point.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Dushan Randikah solutions works for me just added property [0] in front of the items as items[0].firstName